# C# - Set array size

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to create a new class which contains an array but the size of it shouldn't be constant.

Let's say I have the Program.cs and I have a different class called Category.cs.

Category.cs looks like this:

```
class Category
    {
        static int MemberCount = 2;

        private string[] ids = new string[MemberCount];

        public string[] Ids
        {
            get { return ids; }
            set { ids = value; }
        }
...
```

My goal is to somehow modify MemberCount when I create a new object from this Class...

I hope it make sense...

Thank you! :-)

Comment: You want a `List<T>`.

Comment: Particularly when an array has not a fixed size then it is better to use a List

Comment: Thank you. Can you please give me an example who can I use List<T> this case?

Comment: @j0zyv How about using google.

Comment: @j0zyv: it's pretty obvious. Use List<string> instead of an string[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you actually want/need to use an array with the length fixed at object construction time (as opposed to say the `List<T>` wisely suggested in comments), you can add a constructor:

```
class Category
{
    private readonly string[] ids;

    public string[] Ids
    {
        get { return ids; }
    }

    public Category(int memberCount) {
        ids = new string[memberCount];
    }
}
```

Note that I have removed the setter on the `Ids` property as otherwise the array can be overwritten with one of an arbitrary length. Likewise I have made `ids` readonly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [generic list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) or other collection class.

```
class Category 
{
   public List<string> Ids { get; set; }

   Category() 
   {
       Ids = new List<string>();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resize your array using this [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb348051(v=vs.110).aspx/):
Array.Resize(ref ids, newSizeOfArray);